# Empty Class in Swift Playground Gives __lldb_expr_ Error

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, swift-playground

Knocking up an empty class within a Swift Playground gives an error **__lldb_expr_**

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

class FooBar {

}

let foo = FooBar()
```

See attached screenshot. 
[image: __lldb_expr_4 at line 12 on attempted instantiation of class FooBar]

This occurs on Xcode Version **6.3.1 (6D1002)**. I have also tried with the latest Xcode 6.4 beta 3 - **Version 6.4 (6E7)** - available 11th May 2015. The same error occurs.

Empty classes build without issue in a normal Swift project.

The error can be avoided by simply adding a dummy constant as follows:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

class FooBar {
    let wibble = 10
}

let foo = FooBar()
```

Was surprised at this error given that creating a initial empty class is such a basic thing. In my case I wanted a scroll view delegate class to track content offsets. It would seem entirely reasonable to use a delegate with no properties.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not an error.

It's an information that the variable `foo` now holds an object of class `FooBar` whose **internal** name is `__lldb_expr_12.FooBar`. `__lldb_expr_12` is the Swift module's name in the Playground in this case.

Comment: ah, that's good news! So basically with no properties, the __lldb_expr is output as default?

Comment: All your class names are prefixed with `__lldb_expr….` in Playground. All classes must belong to a Swift module which has a name. The class's internal name is then `ModuleName.ClassName`. And since you cannot pick a custom module name in Playground it'll use `__lldb_expr…`. - When you build an app for example it'll be `AppName.ClassName`. - i.e. it does not depend on the properties.

Comment: I tried this in Xcode 11.3.1, what I got is foobar = Optional(LearnARC.Foobar)