# Swift playground __lldb prefix on every instance creation

Tags: swift, xcode, struct, lldb, swift-playground

Regarding Xcode Version 8.3.1 (8E1000a

I have this __lldb_expr_xx prefix on all instances in my playgrounds.
I was hoping someone might have a solution to this issue?

I know what the prefix is, and why it is there on instances without properties etc. But I have this prefix on every single instance.

Example:

```
struct Point {
    var x: Double
    var y: Double
}
var p1 = Point(x: 1, y: 2)
```

line 5 will give me the prefix in the "results" area.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is lldb\_expr in Swift Playground?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31020725/what-is-lldb-expr-in-swift-playground)

Comment: Also: [Empty Class in Swift Playground Gives `__lldb_expr_` Error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30303410/2415822)